# Поиск уникальных букв в строке и поместить результат в Map

Tags: java, алгоритм, коллекции, map

Метод принимает на вход `String`. надо посчитать количество уникальных букв в строке и запихать в `Map<буква, количество повторений>` без использования циклов и условий.
Думал сперва сделать так:

```
List<String> stringChars = Arrays.asList(string.split(""));
```

а потом как-то из листа достать буквы и посчитать их количество. но пока не нашел как.

на просторах гугла попадалось:

```
public Map<Integer, Animal> convertListAfterJava8(List<Animal> list) {
    Map<Integer, Animal> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Animal::getId, animal -> animal));
    return map;
}
```

Но я не знаю как это приспособить к своей задаче, поскольку в этом варианте не примитивы и используются неизвестные мне лямбды.

Comment: без использования циклов и условий только через Stream и лямбды. В ином случаи только через циклы. А ваш вариант едиственное, что делает это получает набор букв, который хранится в листе. Далее необоходимо написать цикл, которые сравнивает буквы и запихивает их в Мап. Потому - или учите Java 8 или же делайте через циклы с условиями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изучайте лямбды. Это поможет при программировании на java 8+.

Вот код (может показаться что он без лямбд, но на самом деле они есть, просто их явно не видно)

```
public static Map<String, Integer> collectCharacters(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.split(""))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```